# MongoDB. How to move a document from one array to another?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Session collection. The collection is as follows:

```
_id:ObjectId(5ce3c94f0e259e7370966c63)
status:Int32(1)
title:String(dfsb)
content:String(fdbfdbfd)
Array(visits):[
]
Array(visits_online):[
    0:Object
        start:Date(2019-05-22T08:06:50.222+00:00)
        _id:ObjectId(5ce5031ae8ee2e83b9ab23ff)
        session_id:ObjectId(5ce3c94f0e259e7370966c63)
        user_id:ObjectId(5ce4f290e2971cc6791e5a11)
        end:Date(2019-05-22T08:06:51.438+00:00)
    1:Object
        start:Date(2019-05-22T08:07:11.512+00:00)
        _id:ObjectId(5ce5032fe8ee2e83b9ab2403)
        session_id:ObjectId(5ce3c94f0e259e7370966c63)
        user_id:ObjectId(5ce4f290e2971cc6791e5a11)
        end:Date(2019-05-22T08:07:11.791+00:00)
]
```

**What I need:**
I want to move a subdocument from the `visits_online` array to the `visits` array

```
_id:ObjectId(5ce3c94f0e259e7370966c63)
status:Int32(1)
title:String(dfsb)
content:String(fdbfdbfd)
Array(visits):[
        0:Object
        start:Date(2019-05-22T08:06:50.222+00:00)
        _id:ObjectId(5ce5031ae8ee2e83b9ab23ff)
        session_id:ObjectId(5ce3c94f0e259e7370966c63)
        user_id:ObjectId(5ce4f290e2971cc6791e5a11)
        end:Date(2019-05-22T08:06:51.438+00:00)
]
Array(visits_online):[
    1:Object
        start:Date(2019-05-22T08:07:11.512+00:00)
        _id:ObjectId(5ce5032fe8ee2e83b9ab2403)
        session_id:ObjectId(5ce3c94f0e259e7370966c63)
        user_id:ObjectId(5ce4f290e2971cc6791e5a11)
        end:Date(2019-05-22T08:07:11.791+00:00)
]
```

**What I tried to do:**

```
Session.update({ _id: '5ce3c94f0e259e7370966c63', 'visits_online._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ce5031ae8ee2e83b9ab23ff') },
        {
            $pull: { 'visits_online._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ce5031ae8ee2e83b9ab23ff') },
            $push: { visits: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ce5031ae8ee2e83b9ab23ff') },
        })
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight mistake in your mongo query, you need to tell mongo which array to pull object from.

Also, you need to pass `ObjectId` instead of `string` to match against `_id` in update query.

Currently you are passing it as `_id : '5ce3c94f0e259e7370966c63'` , but is should be _id : `_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ce3c94f0e259e7370966c63')`

Try this :

```
Session.update({ 
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ce3c94f0e259e7370966c63'), 
    'visits_online._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ce5031ae8ee2e83b9ab23ff') 
},{
    $pull: { visits_online :  { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ce5031ae8ee2e83b9ab23ff') }},
    $push: { visits: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ce5031ae8ee2e83b9ab23ff') },
})
```

For more info read [mongodb $pull documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull). I hope it helps!

Comment: Not working. No changes to the database

Comment: You need to pass `ObjectId` in the first argument of update query, instead of string. I have updated my answer, please have a look

Comment: @LisaEnn did it work?